# Is it possible to upgrade Limesurvey from v 1.9 to 4.2

Tags: limesurvey

We need to upgrade our limesurvey version from 1.9 to 4.2 (Completely new linux server, php version and mysql version)
The upgrade documentation includes only from 1.5 to 2.x or 2.x to the newest version

So is there any documentation on how to safely upgrade without loosing the existing surveys and users?

Answer (score 2):

My advices :

1. **make a backup** …
2. Make another backup

Else : 2nd advice : update to 3LTS not to 4.

You can upgrade from 1.9 to last 3LTS without issue, but think it's best if you do it 2 or 3 steps.

1. Upgrade to https://github.com/SondagesPro/LimeSurvey-SondagesPro/tree/2.06_SondagesPro
2. Upgrade to https://github.com/SondagesPro/LimeSurvey-SondagesPro/tree/2.73
3. Finally upgrade to https://www.limesurvey.org/lts-releases-download

What can broke :

1. Theme and template (100% sure)
2. Javascript and css workaroung